# No connectivity between EC2 instance and Docker container

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, connectivity

I have an EC2 instance (Ubuntu 16.04 ami-ba602bc2) deployed.  I've installed docker on it and downloaded a Docker container that runs JasperReports in Tomcat.  I've tested this Docker container on my laptop and it works correctly.  I downloaded and started the Docker container on the EC2 instance with

```
docker run -itd -p 8080:8080 dwschulze/jasperreports.server.v7.1.ubuntu.16.04:latest
```

the same command I use locally to run on my laptop.  `docker ps` shows the container running.  I've opened port 8080 in the AWS security group.

I've also connected to the Docker container and verified that the tomcat instance is running.

I can't connect to the reports server from the internet.  I've also tried `telnet localhost 8080` from the EC2 instance and it times out.

Everything I've read says that I should be able to run a Docker container on an EC2 instance, but it can't even connect locally.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was running in a t2.small which is too small to even run Tomcat (let alone Jasper Reports) reliably. I switched to a t2.xlarge and problem solved.